# How to create an application in IIS using command line?

Tags: iis, command-line, iis-6, batch-file

What would be the equivalent, by command line, of the create button in the Home Directory tab in IIS 6.0 ? (Used to create an application on a directory).

Edit :
I already know of iidvdir. Unfortunalety, it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to (or I dont use it properly). Let's say that I have a website called *Website* for witch the root directory is C:\Website. I want to create the application in C:\Website\Application. If i try

```
iisvdir /create Website Application c:\website\Application
```

I get the message The virtual directory already exists. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iisvdir /create Website Application c:\website\Application

It will only works if the directory C:\Website\Application doesn't already exists. If the directory exists, you will get the *The virtual directory already* exists message.

Comment: FYI: IIsWeb /create "Website Application" to create the site.

Answer (score 3):

[Command-line Tools Included in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525006(loband).aspx). In-particular `%SystemRoot%\System32\IIsVdir.vbs`.

Comment: Please add a reason if you're going to downvote. Also, look at the accepted answer :)

Comment: this seems to not be present in Windows2012Server

Answer (score 1):

use IIsVDir.vbs  (look in windows\system32\IIsVDir.vbs)