# IIS: how to undeploy/delete/remove a webapp from command line?

Tags: iis, web-applications, command-line

Suppose there's a webapp deployed on local IIS server. When I need to remove/undeploy it, I can go to IIS Manager, right-click on the app, and then select "Delete application and content" - et voila. But, I need to do the same from the command line - how? It can be assumed that the name of the application is known.

Maybe this can be done via MSDeploy somehow?

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610880/how-to-create-an-application-in-iis-using-command-line

Answer (score 19):

If you just want to remove the application from the Web Site in IIS without physically deleting the files (like `msdeploy` does) or if you don't have the WebDeploy-extension installed, you can use the following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe delete app "Default Web Site/MyAppName"
```

Comment: It might be good to note that appcmd is only for IIS 7+ only, otherwise the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @Stephan Bauer, I want to use appcmd delete more applications once time,  how to do it?  I look forward  to your reply, thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry, but the only possibility I know (to delete multiple applications at once) is to create a batch file (or sth. similiar) that calls `appcmd` multiple times.

Comment: [This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771205(v=ws.10)) was useful for me as well to delete the application on IIS.

Answer (score 14):

This is what did it:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy" -verb:delete -dest:apphostconfig="Default Web Site/<webapp_name>"
```

Comment: Just to save time, in Windows 8 boxes running IIS 8 it could be `"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy" -verb:delete -dest:apphostconfig="Default Web Site/<webapp_name>"`

Answer (score 5):

I know the question says "command line", but you can use PowerShell and the [IIS Administration Cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx) to do this task. I provide all of the functions and explain the process of how to automate this [on my blog](http://blog.danskingdom.com/powershell-functions-to-convert-remove-and-delete-iis-web-applications/). Also, you can easily swap out the IIS Administration Cmdlet calls with calls to msdeploy, appcmd, IIsVdir.vbs, etc.

For your specific question, this PowerShell code should do the trick:

```
$block = {
    Import-Module WebAdministration
    $website = "YourWebsiteName"
    $applicationName = "PathUnderWebsite\ToYourApplication"

    $fullPath = Join-Path $website $applicationName
    Write-Host "Checking if we need to remove '$fullPath'..."
    if (Get-WebApplication -Site "$website" -Name "$applicationName")
    {
        Write-Host "Removing '$fullPath'..."
        Remove-WebApplication -Site "$website" -Name "$applicationName"
    }

    Write-Host "Deleting the directory '$fullPath'..."
    Remove-Item -Path "IIS:\Sites\$fullPath" -Recurse -Force
}
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "Your.WebServer.HostName"
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $block
Remove-PSSession -Session $session
```

Comment: If working locally, you don't need all the `PSSession` stuff. +1, though.

Answer (score 2):

iisweb /delete WebSite [/s Computer [/u [Domain ]User /p Password ]]

Comment: 'iisweb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

If that helps, I'm running server 2008 R2, so IIS is v7.

Comment: i rhink you shoud use appcmd http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe